# Consume SOAP API from WSO2 ECLIPSE Developer Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I need solution to consume two SOAP APIs .

First i have a wsdl url which will work once certificate installed on machine i just want to ask that is there any type of configuration need to be done on developer studio while creating the flow.

Second i need to make a flow in wso2 developer studio which will call a SOAP WSDL URL and gives response but the problem is that the wsdl contains security policy username-token ws-security configuration any expert tell me the flow for that.

Both scenarios work in SOAP UI tool. I am new to wso2 anyone can help me in this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question the answer is no. Certificate of the server should only be stored in the client side. When a TLS/SSL enabled URL is called, the server's certificate should be stored in the client's trust store. If your client is a WSO2 server, then that certificate should be imported to the *client-truststore.jks* of the WSO2 server. That is deployment specific. Nothing has to be done during the artifacts are developed in the Developer Studio.

Answer (score 0):

(1) There isn't anything to be done with dev studio. You need to import the backend's certificate to the trust store of the WSO2 server.

(2) You can create a proxy service and call the secured backend. Since your backend is secured by UT policy, you have to construct a username token when calling it. We can use a class mediator to construct and set a username token.

More details can be found at : http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/03/25/how-to-esb-invoking-username-token-secured-backend-service/

Following is the simplified version of the class mediator.

```
public class UTTokenBuilder extends AbstractMediator{
    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        try {
            org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext context = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext)
                    .getAxis2MessageContext();
            context.getOptions().setUserName("admin");
            context.getOptions().setPassword("admin");
            return true;
        } catch (SynapseException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SynapseException("Error while building UT Token");
        }
    }
}
```

And following is the sample proxy to call the secured backend.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="sec2"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <class name="org.soasecurity.wssecurity.ut.mediator.UTTokenBuilder"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://localhost:8243/services/secTestProxy">
                  <enableSec policy="conf:/UTPolicy.xml"/>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Please note I've used an address endpoint for simplicity.